# does yocto have a package called realpath

Tags: yocto

I need to add `realpath` to `RDEPENDS_${PN}` variable in a `**.bbapend` file, but I get this error:

```
Nothing RPROVIDES 'realpath' (but /home/.../recipes-xxx/images/xxx-image-xx.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
```

Is it the wrong package name or what? really don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`realpath` utility is provided by `coreutils` or `busybox` packages. If you want to use coreutils then add

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "coreutils"
```

to your image recipe or you can also add it via `RDEPENDS_${PN}`

For busybox you need to make sure `CONFIG_REALPATH=y` is set in `defconfig` for busybox.

This can be defined via a busybox_%.bbappend as well

```
SRC_URI_append = " file://custom.cfg "
```

where `custom.cfg` has

```
CONFIG_REALPATH=y
```

and is placed in `busybox` folder next to `busybox_%.bbappend`

Comment: Thank you. So there's no way that I can add `realpath` independently?

Comment: not out of box. But you can modify coreutils recipe to package it into a separate output package of its own like `PACKAGES += "coreutils-realpath" and then `FILES_coreutils-realpath` = "${bindir}/realpath"` then you will be able to add `IMAGE_INSTALL += "coreutils-realpath"` to your image and all you will get it just one binary from coreutils installed. if you use busybox approach then busybox is a single binary anyway and it will be a small applet to call into busybox.